# How i can assign the data of a UITextField to a variable?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextfield, iphone-developer-program

I used this code to do it, but it doesn't work and put a issues that is imposible to assign to a variable from string

CODE:

```
numeroJugador1 = numeroIngresa1.text; 
numeroJugador2 = numeroIngresa2.text; 
numeroJugador3 = numeroIngresa3.text;
```

Comment: Include the error you're getting and the code that produces that error.

Comment: incompatible pointer to integrer convertion assigning "int" from "UITextField".

Comment: ... if the numeroJugador variables are ints and you're trying to assign NSString* to them and you don't immediately understand why that shouldn't work then you should probably find a book or tutorial on programming (C, C++, or Obj-C; any will work) and start from the beginning.

Comment: You originally tagged this as `C++`.  That is a concern, because you can only use `UITextField` from the Objective-C programming language.  Are you aware that Objective-C is not C++, and in particular its string class (`NSString`) is very different from the C++ string class (`std::string`)?  (Yes, you can use both, have Objective-C++ - but that just increases the potential for type mismatches like this one.)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
NSString *numeroJugador1 = numerIngress1.text;
```

Comment: it doesn't work because im using the variable in a IF and it takes an error